# how to execute logic downstream of splitter / aggregator for an empty collection

Tags: spring-integration-dsl

how to execute logic downstream/below-of a splitter / aggregator for an empty collection ?
To solve that problem, the only 2 solutions I've found so far is to either use some kind of "goto"  discard channel (see below code) which I personally find a bit "hacky", OR to wrap my splitter/aggregator inside a scattergatherer with 2 subflows (one to deal with empty collections and the other to deal with non-empty collections) which I personally find a bit verbose.

```
MessageChannel bypass = MessageChannels.direct().getObject();
return IntegrationFlows.from(inputChannel)
       .split(new DefaultMessageSplitter(),c -> discardChannel(bybass))
       .log(Level.INFO, m -> "element:"+m)
       .aggregate()
       .channel(bypass)
       .log(Level.INFO, m -> "collection:"+m)
       .channel(outputChannel)
       .getObject();
```

Is there a different/better way to deal with this issue ?
Thanks a lot in advance for your expertise and your time.
Best Regards